# Swing issue with disappearing JTextField

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I'm working in NetBeans, trying to do my project, but I have encountered a problem. Basically, I'm building a digital timer, milliseconds are displayed as as 7 textfields arranged in a shape of 8.

Like this:

```
   _
|     |
   _
|     |
   _
```

for each millisecond I make certain text fields invisible to display different number. Than I have a one second Display which (when milliseconds count up to 10) displays seconds e.g. 1, 2, 3... but for some reason when milliseconds reach 10 a middle textfield disappears and doesn't show up again. I have no idea what could cause this problem.

Here is my code:

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * 
 */
public class TimerFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form TimerFrame
     */
    public TimerFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {

        digitValue = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField3 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField4 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField5 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField6 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField7 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        showDigit = new javax.swing.JButton();
        AddOne = new javax.swing.JButton();
        oneSecs = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        showOneSecs = new javax.swing.JButton();
        oneSecsDisplay = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Digital Timer");
        setBackground(new java.awt.Color(70, 70, 70));
        setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));

        digitValue.setText("000");

        jTextField1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 0));
        jTextField1.setText("     ");

        jTextField2.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 0));
        jTextField2.setText("  ");

        jTextField3.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 0));
        jTextField3.setText("  ");

        jTextField4.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 0));
        jTextField4.setText("     ");

        jTextField5.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 0));
        jTextField5.setText("  ");

        jTextField6.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 0));
        jTextField6.setText("  ");
        jTextField6.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jTextField6ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jTextField7.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 0));
        jTextField7.setText("     ");

        showDigit.setText("Show the Digit");
        showDigit.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                showDigitActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        AddOne.setText("Add One");
        AddOne.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                AddOneActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        oneSecs.setText("0");

        showOneSecs.setText("Show One Secs");
        showOneSecs.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                showOneSecsActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout layout = new org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
            .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .add(60, 60, 60)
                .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
                    .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .add(226, 226, 226)
                        .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
                            .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .add(8, 8, 8)
                                .add(oneSecsDisplay, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 96, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .add(62, 62, 62)
                                .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
                                    .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.TRAILING, false)
                                        .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                            .add(jTextField2, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 13, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                            .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.RELATED, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                            .add(jTextField3, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 13, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                        .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                            .add(jTextField5, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 13, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                            .add(28, 28, 28)
                                            .add(jTextField6, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 13, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                                    .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                        .add(10, 10, 10)
                                        .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
                                            .add(jTextField7, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 34, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                            .add(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
                                                    .add(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.TRAILING, jTextField4, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 34, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                    .add(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.TRAILING, jTextField1, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                                .add(10, 10, 10))))))
                            .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .add(showOneSecs)
                                .add(6, 6, 6)
                                .add(AddOne)
                                .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.RELATED)
                                .add(showDigit)
                                .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.RELATED)
                                .add(digitValue, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                        .addContainerGap(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .add(272, 272, 272)
                        .add(oneSecs, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .add(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
            .add(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(104, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .add(oneSecs, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.RELATED)
                .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.TRAILING)
                    .add(oneSecsDisplay, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 120, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .add(jTextField1, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 13, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.RELATED)
                        .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.BASELINE)
                            .add(jTextField3, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .add(jTextField2, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.RELATED)
                        .add(jTextField4, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 13, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.RELATED)
                        .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.BASELINE)
                            .add(jTextField6, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .add(jTextField5, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .add(7, 7, 7)
                        .add(jTextField7, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 13, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.RELATED)
                .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
                    .add(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.TRAILING, showOneSecs)
                    .add(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.TRAILING, layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.BASELINE)
                        .add(digitValue, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .add(showDigit)
                        .add(AddOne)))
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>

    private void jTextField6ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }

    private void showDigitActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        // showDigit
        int digit1 = Integer.parseInt(digitValue.getText());
        jTextField1.setVisible(true);
        jTextField2.setVisible(true);
        jTextField3.setVisible(true);
        jTextField4.setVisible(true);
        jTextField5.setVisible(true);
        jTextField6.setVisible(true);
        jTextField7.setVisible(true);
            if (digit1 == 0) {
                jTextField4.setVisible(false);
            } else if (digit1 == 1) {
                jTextField1.setVisible(false);
                jTextField2.setVisible(false);
                jTextField4.setVisible(false);
                jTextField5.setVisible(false);
                jTextField7.setVisible(false);
            } else if (digit1 == 2) {
                jTextField2.setVisible(false);
                jTextField6.setVisible(false);
            } else if (digit1 == 3) {
                jTextField2.setVisible(false);
                jTextField5.setVisible(false);
            } else if (digit1 == 4) {
                jTextField1.setVisible(false);
                jTextField5.setVisible(false);
                jTextField7.setVisible(false);
            } else if (digit1 == 5) {
                jTextField3.setVisible(false);
                jTextField5.setVisible(false);
            } else if (digit1 == 6) {
                jTextField3.setVisible(false);
            } else if (digit1 == 7) {
                jTextField2.setVisible(false);
                jTextField4.setVisible(false);
                jTextField5.setVisible(false);
                jTextField7.setVisible(false);
            } else if (digit1 == 9) {
                jTextField5.setVisible(false);
            }
    }

    private void AddOneActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        // Add One
        int addOne = Integer.parseInt(digitValue.getText());
        addOne = addOne + 1;
        if (addOne == 10) { 
            addOne = 0;
            int oneSecond = Integer.parseInt(oneSecs.getText());
            oneSecond = oneSecond + 1;
            String oneSeconds = Integer.toString(oneSecond);
            oneSecs.setText(oneSeconds);
            showOneSecsActionPerformed(evt);
        }
        String myString = Integer.toString(addOne);
        digitValue.setText(myString);
        showDigitActionPerformed(evt);
    }

    private void showOneSecsActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        // Show One Secs
        int ones = Integer.parseInt(oneSecs.getText());
            if (ones == 0) {
                oneSecsDisplay.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("0.jpg"));
            } else if (ones == 1) {
                oneSecsDisplay.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("1.jpg"));
            } else if (ones == 2) {
                oneSecsDisplay.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("2.jpg"));
            } else if (ones == 3) {
                oneSecsDisplay.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("3.jpg"));
            } else if (ones == 4) {
                oneSecsDisplay.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("4.jpg"));
            } else if (ones == 5) {
                oneSecsDisplay.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("5.jpg"));
            } else if (ones == 6) {
                oneSecsDisplay.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("6.jpg"));
            } else if (ones == 7) {
                oneSecsDisplay.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("7.jpg"));
            } else if (ones == 8) {
                oneSecsDisplay.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("8.jpg"));
            } else if (ones == 9) {
                oneSecsDisplay.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("9.jpg"));
            }
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TimerFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TimerFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TimerFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(TimerFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new TimerFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JButton AddOne;
    private javax.swing.JTextField digitValue;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField3;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField4;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField5;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField6;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField7;
    private javax.swing.JTextField oneSecs;
    private javax.swing.JButton oneSecsDisplay;
    private javax.swing.JButton showDigit;
    private javax.swing.JButton showOneSecs;
    // End of variables declaration
}
```

Comment: I've taken the liberty of adjusting the title and tags since this is really a java Swing problem.

Comment: Why are you using JTextFields?  Just draw the bars that make up the 8 shape onto an extension of JPanel.

Comment: There are more than 10 milliseconds in one second (1000 to be precise).

Comment: That NetBeans generated code!

Comment: Neat!  I ran your code, but could not see any issue.  You'll have to be clearer about what is wrong.  Also, as others have said, using JTextFields here is weird.  You should look into Java 2D Graphics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As madth3 has pointed out, once a component is made invisible, it's no longer considered by most layout managers when they calculate there layouts.

While I can think of 100 different ways to approach this problem, the following example uses a simple `JPanel` that acts as a segment and uses a funky alpha color trick to "hide" segments that doesn't effect the existing layout.

[image]

```
public class Clock {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Clock();
    }

    public Clock() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TimerPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TimerPane extends JPanel {

        private List<Segment> segments;
        private int tick = 0;

        public TimerPane() {
            setBorder(new EmptyBorder(9, 9, 9, 9));
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            segments = new ArrayList<>(7);
            segments.add(new Segment(false));
            segments.add(new Segment(true));
            segments.add(new Segment(true));
            segments.add(new Segment(false));
            segments.add(new Segment(true));
            segments.add(new Segment(true));
            segments.add(new Segment(false));

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 1;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            add(segments.get(0), gbc);
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(segments.get(1), gbc);
            gbc.gridx = 2;
            add(segments.get(2), gbc);

            gbc.gridx = 1;
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(segments.get(3), gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            add(segments.get(4), gbc);
            gbc.gridx = 2;
            add(segments.get(5), gbc);

            gbc.gridx = 1;
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(segments.get(6), gbc);

            Timer clock = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    List<Segment> active = new ArrayList<Segment>(segments);
                    switch (tick) {
                        case 0:
                            active.remove(segments.get(3));
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            active.remove(segments.get(0));
                            active.remove(segments.get(1));
                            active.remove(segments.get(3));
                            active.remove(segments.get(4));
                            active.remove(segments.get(6));
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            active.remove(segments.get(1));
                            active.remove(segments.get(5));
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            active.remove(segments.get(1));
                            active.remove(segments.get(4));
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            active.remove(segments.get(0));
                            active.remove(segments.get(4));
                            active.remove(segments.get(6));
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            active.remove(segments.get(2));
                            active.remove(segments.get(4));
                            break;
                        case 6:
                            active.remove(segments.get(2));
                            break;
                        case 7:
                            active.remove(segments.get(1));
                            active.remove(segments.get(3));
                            active.remove(segments.get(4));
                            active.remove(segments.get(6));
                            break;
                        case 8:
                            break;
                        case 9:
                            active.remove(segments.get(4));
                            active.remove(segments.get(6));
                            break;
                    }

                    List<Segment> inactive = new ArrayList<>(segments);
                    inactive.removeAll(active);

                    color(active, true);
                    color(inactive, false);

                    tick++;
                    if (tick > 9) {
                        tick = 0;
                    }

                    repaint();

                }

                protected void color(List<Segment> segments, boolean isActive) {
                    for (Segment segment : segments) {
                        segment.setActive(isActive);
                    }
                }
            });
            clock.setInitialDelay(0);
            clock.setRepeats(true);
            clock.start();

        }
    }

    public class Segment extends JPanel {

        protected Color alpha = new Color(0, 0, 0, 0);

        private boolean vertical;
        private boolean active;

        public Segment(boolean vertical) {
            this.vertical = vertical;
            setActive(false);
        }

        public void setActive(boolean value) {
            if (active != value) {
                active = value;
                if (active) {
                    setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
                    setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.DARK_GRAY));
                } else {
                    setBackground(alpha);
                    setBorder(new LineBorder(alpha));
                }
            }
        }

        public boolean isActive() {
            return active;
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            Dimension size = super.getPreferredSize();
            if (vertical) {
                size = new Dimension(5, 15);
            } else {
                size = new Dimension(15, 5);
            }
            return size;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi thank you for the answer, but I need to do it exact way as I mentioned, as it is required for uni project, I could've done this different and more efficient way, but have to stick to the rules ;/

Comment: So, instead of using the panels, replace them with text fields

Answer (score 1):

For starters I'd have to say this is a very unusual implementation of a number display. Changing element's visibility can cause components to re-layout and problems like this to occur.

The problem is caused by the call to change icon's on the button `oneSecsDisplay` as it can be seen commenting out the call to `showOneSecsActionPerformed`. The layout repacks everything and it disappears the JTextField in the middle.

I'm no expert in the GroupLayout but a possible short solution would be to put all those TextFields into a panel of it's own. In the long run I agree with @whiskeyspider in recommending [a drawing alternative](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html).