# How do I display all digits in the animation?

Tags: java, swing, timer

I am having troubles with displaying an animation of digits counting up.
I am using a timer to count from zero to one. Although the timer works,
it skips displaying zero, and jumps to displaying one.
Could anyone tell me how I can make it so it displays zero first then one next?
(The default background is set to the color white)

Here is the code I am using.

```
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class SevenSegment extends JFrame {
    Timer timer = new Timer(1000, null);

public SevenSegment() {
timer.start();
        
        timer.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                
                JLabel[][] zero = {{lblOne, lblTwo, lblThree, lblFour, lblFive, lblSix},{lblSeven}};
                JLabel[][] one = {{lblFive, lblSix}, {lblOne, lblTwo, lblThree, lblFour, lblSeven}};
               
                for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                    if (i==0) {
                        for (JLabel a: zero[0]) {
                            a.setBackground(Color.RED);
                            for(JLabel b: zero[1]) {
                                b.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                           }
                        }
                    }
                    
                    if (i==1) {
                        for (JLabel a: one[0]) {
                            a.setBackground(Color.RED);
                            for(JLabel b: one[1]) {
                                b.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    
            
                }

            
            }
        });
   }
}
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) A single blank line of white space in source code is all that is *ever* needed.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant.

Comment: At a guess I'd say the (main) problem) is starting the `Timer` before action listener is set, but a) I don't like guessing, and b) I'll look more closely at it when there is [mre].

Comment: A `Timer` is a pseudo loop, each time it's called, you need to do a single step in the loop

Comment: And [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13291664/swing-issue-with-disappearing-jtextfield/13301300#13301300)